# "Add reference" and *.csproj file in VS2012

Tags: .net, clr

My understanding is, **if I use "Add refenrce" to add some DLLs to my project, these reference info will be stored in the *.csproj file like below, and it should be stored in the assembly manifest after compilation.**

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=11.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

And these info should be be reflected in the assembly metadata manifest, which could be checked with ILDasm.exe.

But I noticed that some referenced DLL only shows up in the *.csproj file, but **not** in the assembly manifest.

Such as:

In *.csproj, I have:

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=11.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=11.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=11.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=11.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

But in assembly manifest, I only see this:

```
.assembly extern Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
{
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A )                         // .?_....:
  .ver 11:0:0:0
}

.assembly extern Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
{
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A )                         // .?_....:
  .ver 11:0:0:0
}
```

Since I didn't see some assemblies in the manifest, **I removed them from the reference list, but the project won't even build.**

Is there anything I misundersatnd about .NET CLR?

And here's another a related thread may be related:
[VS2012 failed to keep consistent DLL version in *.csproj file and assembly manifest, a VS2012 bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019925/vs2012-failed-to-keep-consistent-dll-version-in-csproj-file-and-assembly-manif)

### Update

In the above, I said **I removed them from the reference list, but the project won't even build.** This is not true.

I removed the DLL references not mentioned in the assembly manifest, the project still builds well.
And these info are also removed from *.csproj file.

So I think we **do can** put some un-necessary refernces in the project, and these info **will** goes into the *.csproj file. But it will **NOT** go into the assembly manifest if the compiler consider the reference is un-necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: You should cut the Update section andn paste as an answer. Then after one day you can accept your own answer and close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly or Project reference (ie "stored in the *.csproj" as Reference or ProjectReference) not actually used in code are not included in generated assembly. It's a standard behavior.

Some tools like Resharper can help you to remove them.